# How to create a command link in salesforce1 to open a record?

Tags: salesforce1-app, datatable, commandlink

I have a vf Page with Data table where record name is a link like this

```
 <apex:CommandLink value="{!m.what.name}" action="/{!m.what.id}" target="_Blank"/>
```

This opens in a new tab in web UI

In the similar manner If I want to open a record Detail in Salesforce1 in the Datatable
what is the link.

Above link in Salesforce1 doesn't open the Record.

I've already tried the link

```
sforce.one.navigateToURL();
```

it doesn't open record detail in Salesforce1...it's a blank white page I am getting.

Comment: @Eric I don't want to open VF page ...I want to open record detail in App

Comment: then use navigate to sObject

Comment: can u Elaborate please. @Eric

Answer (score 0):

See [Navigation with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) for details on how to use SF1 specific navigation commands. Specifically, you'll want to use `navigateToSObject(​recordId​[, view])`.